# Seeking a Faster way to update MySql database

Tags: mysql, database, import, database-performance

I have a database with data that is read-only as far as the application using it is concerned. However, different groups of tables within the database need to be refreshed weekly, or monthly (the organization generating the data provides entirely new flat files for this purpose).  Most of the updates are small but some are large (more than 5 million rows with a large number of fields).  I like to load the data to a test database and then just replace the entire database in production.  So far I have been doing this by exporting the data using mysqldump and then importing it into production. The problem is that the import takes 6-8 hours and the system is unusable during that time.

I would like to get the downtime as short as possible. I’ve tried all the tips I could find to speed mysqldump, such as those listed here:  http://vitobotta.com/smarter-faster-backups-restores-mysql-databases-with-mysqldump/#sthash.cQ521QnX.hpG7WdMH.dpbs.  I know that many people recommend Percona’s XtraBackup, but unfortunately I’m on a Windows 8 Server and Perconia does not run on Windows. Other fast backups/restore options are too expensive (e.g., MySql Enterprise). Since my test server and production server are both 64 bit Windows machines and are both running the same version of MySql,(5.6)  I thought I could just zip up the database files and copy them over to swap out the whole database at once (all are innodb). However, that didn’t work. I saw the tables in MySql Workbench, but couldn’t access them.

I’d like to know if copying the database files is a viable option (I may have done it wrong) and if it is not, then what low cost options are available to reduce my downtime?

Comment: If it didn't work, it might be because you have an InnoDB database which does not keep the data where you expect.

Comment: Voted to be moved to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Where does it keep the data then?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read all the way thru first time, I was able to get copying and pasting the table to work in the context of replicating an encrypted table between 2 servers, though definitely took a few tries to get it to work the first time. What was the reason it failed? What got me was table compression settings on both servers must be the same.